# C# Игральный кубик с неравномерной вероятностью

Tags: c#

Имеется игральный кубик с **N** количеством граней, сейчас вполне хватит **6**. Кубик является не вполне честным, так как шанс выпадения граней неравномерный. Тем не менее, при броске гарантированно выпадает **одна** из граней.

Шансы выпадения граней этого кубика:

> 1. 10%
> 2. 15%
> 3. 40%
> 4. 5%
> 5. 10%
> 6. 20%

---

Примерная структура игрального кубика:

```
public struct Dice
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Edges of a <see cref="Dice"/>
    /// </summary>
    public Dictionary<int, double> Edges { get; private set; }

    public Dice(Dictionary<int, double> edges)
    {
        this.Edges = edges;
    }

    public int Roll()
    {
        // some code
        return default;
    }
}
```

---

Как можно реализовать бросок такого кубика, а затем вернуть номер выпавшей грани?

Comment: Конвертируйте массив вероятностей в накопительный. Для приведённого примера: 1 - от 0% до 10%, 2 - от 10% до 25%, ... 6 - от 80% до 100%. И теперь генерите рандомное число и смотрите, в какой диапазон оно попадает.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Не успел до ответа [@Александра Муксимова](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/230392/%d0%90%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%80-%d0%9c%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b2). По сути, мой ответ содержит те же идеи, что и у автора принятого ответа.

---

Реализация проста. Необходимо представить в голове **колесо рулетки**, где **каждый сектор - это граница кубика, а его размер - это вероятность выпадения грани кубика.** Т.е. процесс бросания кубика превращается в процесс вращения рулетки. Вот, как это можно представить:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо этот процесс вращения аппроксимировать на прямую длиной от 0 до 1. Т.е. необходимо разбить прямую на "секторы", где длина сектора вычисляется по формуле:

```
L(сектора i) = (1 / 100) * P(вероятность выпадения сектора i в процентах).
```

Реализация алгоритма представлена ниже. Не делал проверок на правильность указанных значений в `edges`, поскольку хотел показать основную идею, а дописать ее будет несложно.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var edges = new Dictionary<int, double>
    {
        {1, 10},
        {2, 15},
        {3, 40},
        {4, 5},
        {5, 10},
        {6, 20}
    };
    
    var dice = new Dice(edges);

    var rollCount = 100;
    var actualProbabilities = edges.Select(p => p.Key).ToDictionary(p => p, p => 0);
    for (var i = 0; i < rollCount; i++)
    {
        var edge = dice.Roll();
        actualProbabilities[edge]++;
        
        Console.WriteLine($"Roll #{i}: Edge {edge}");
    }

    foreach (var p in actualProbabilities)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Edge #{p.Key} has actual probability {p.Value * 1.0d / rollCount}");
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}

public class Dice
{
    private readonly Roulette _roulette;

    public Dice(Dictionary<int, double> edges)
    {
        _roulette = CreateRoulette(edges);
    }

    public int Roll()
    {
        var sector = _roulette.Roll();
        return sector.Id;
    }

    private static Roulette CreateRoulette(Dictionary<int, double> edges)
    {
        var sectors = new List<Sector>();

        const double onePercentLength = 1.0d / 100;
        double sectorFrom = 0;
        foreach (var edge in edges)
        {
            var sectorTo = sectorFrom + edge.Value * onePercentLength;
            var sector = new Sector(edge.Key, sectorFrom, sectorTo);
            sectors.Add(sector);

            sectorFrom = sectorTo;
        }

        var roulette = new Roulette(sectors);
        return roulette;
    }
}

public class Sector
{
    public double From { get; }
    public double To { get; }
    public int Id { get; }

    public Sector(int id, double from, double to)
    {
        Id = id;
        From = from;
        To = to;
    }
}

public class Roulette
{
    private static readonly Random _random = new Random();
    private readonly List<Sector> _sectors;

    public Roulette(List<Sector> sectors)
    {
        _sectors = sectors;
    }

    public Sector Roll()
    {
        var r = _random.NextDouble();

        foreach (var sector in _sectors)
        {
            if (IsValueInSector(r, sector))
            {
                return sector;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    private static bool IsValueInSector(double value, Sector sector)
    {
        return value >= sector.From && value < sector.To;
    }
}
```

Протестировать, поиграться можно [тут](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2aaFZm)

Comment: Вы проделали потрясающую работу!

Comment: Работа интересная, но, как по мне, то слишком сложно все устроено. На такую задачу слишком много телодвижений и слишком много кода. Как следствие - слишком много мест для потенциальных багов.

Comment: @Qubk спасибо! Код имеет некоторое количество недочетов, исправлять которые я уже не стал, поэтому потрясающей работу сложно назвать. Она лишь кажется потрясающей из-за того, что я алгоритм переложил на пример из реального мира, и добавил яркую картинку :)

Answer (score 14):

Для датчика с равномерным распределением случайных чисел на отрезке `[A,B]`, вероятность попадания в некоторый отрезок `[a,b]`, принадлежащий `[A,B]` (`a>A` и `b<B`) пропорциональна длине этого отрезка `(b-a)/(B-A)`. Следовательно Ваша задача разбить интервал распределения случайной величины вашего датчика на множество не пересекающихся отрезков, с длиной пропорциональной заданной вероятности.

Для того создаем в Вашем классе генератор случайных чисел:

```
public class Dice
{
    //...
    Random rnd;
    //...
}
```

Поскольку у Вас шансы выпадения граней заданы в процентах, то дабы не заморачиваться будем генерировать целые случайные числа в интервале `1,100`. Тогда Ваша искомая функция будет иметь вид:

```
public int Roll()
{
    int p = rnd.Next(1, 101); // правая граница Random не входит в интервал

    if (p <= 10) return 1;
    if (p > 10 && p <= 25) return 2;
    if (p > 25 && p <= 65) return 3;
    if (p > 65 && p <= 70) return 4;
    if (p > 70 && p <= 80) return 5;
    if (p > 80) return 6;
    throw new Exception("Вот сейчас совсем неожиданно было");
}
```

---

То же самое, только с использованием синтаксиса C# 9.0 (.NET 5)

```
public int Roll() => rnd.Next(1, 101) switch
{
    > 80 => 6,
    > 70 => 5,
    > 65 => 4,
    > 25 => 3,
    > 10 => 2,
    _ => 1
};
```

Comment: @aepot, спасибо за правку - она по делу :). У меня нет сейчас под рукой среды с C#, поэтому не было возможности все проверить.

Comment: Не за что, в качестве развлечения добавил еще C# 9.0, вдруг кому-нибудь пригодится.

Answer (score 11):

А мне больше всего нравится простота и "дубовость" ответа Vladimir Gamalyan.

Я решил развить его идею до следующего кода:

```
private int[] dist = new[] {
                  //(цифра кубика, возможность выпадения)
   Enumerable.Repeat(1, 10),
   Enumerable.Repeat(2, 15),
   Enumerable.Repeat(3, 40),
   Enumerable.Repeat(4, 5 ),
   Enumerable.Repeat(5, 10),
   Enumerable.Repeat(6, 20)
}
.SelectMany(a => a).ToArray();

private Random random = new Random();

public int Roll() => dist[random.Next(dist.Length)];
```

Как следствие: код простой, дубовый, легко читается, легко правится, и, вероятно, самый быстро работающий из всех предложенных. (хотя нет, код aepot на C#9 работает быстрее)

Кроме того - возможность выпадения пишется БУКВАЛЬНОЙ ТОЧНОЙ ЦИФРОЙ. А не относительной. Т.е. если возможность 25 - то это 25, а не > 10 && < 35.

Еще из плюсов кода - можно развить возможность выпадения и до сотой процента легким движением руки:

```
Enumerable.Repeat(1, 1.11 * 100), //1,11%
Enumerable.Repeat(2, 15   * 100), //15%
```

У этого кода я вижу только один недостаток - при большой точности будет занято "много" места в оперативке. Но т.к. задача этого не предполагает изначально - то и особо недостатком можно это и не считать.

Comment: Как дополнительный плюс (а может и минус для кого-то) - сумма вероятностей не обязана быть равна стам, как в других ответах.

Comment: Да и можно сделать с этого кода рулетку на любое количество значений, а не только кубик. Буквально парой легких изменений)

Comment: Тут не поспоришь, высший пилотаж :).Если количество граней `N` ограничено небольшими значениями, то лучше и не придумать

Comment: `private var` - это новый синтаксис c# или описка?

Comment: я пишу с мака не проверяя в вижуалке чисто по памяти, так что, вероятно, описка) Не уверен сейчас в своей памяти синтаксиса шарпа))

Answer (score 9):

Как альтернатива, более шустрый и тупой вариант (но в общем случае неудобный и не везде применимый) это создать массив с нужным количеством тех или иных вариантов и выбирать уже из него рандомом по его размеру:

```
public int Roll()
{
    Random random = new Random();

    var dist = new []{1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6};
    return dist[random.Next(dist.Length)];
}
```

* *edges здесь не учитывается*

Comment: мне этот ответ нравится больше всего из-за его простоты. Но я решил развинуть идею этого ответа и сделал свой вариант)

Answer (score 6):

```
public int Roll()
{
  Random random = new Random();
  double r = random.NextDouble();
  double p = 0;
  foreach(int key in edges.Keys)
  {
    if (p <= r && r < p + edges[key])
      return key;
    p = p + edges[key];
  }
  return -1;
}
```