# Как сделать выбор в зависимости от полученого случайного числа?

Tags: c#, unity3d, случайные-числа

Я получаю случайное число ( от 0 - 100 ( не целое) ) и нужно например что если число меньше или равно 10, то сделать что-то, а если число больше 10, но меньше или равно 20, то выполнить что-то.

Проблема того способа, который у меня - это то, что шансы могут быть одинаковы и тогда выполнится первое такое условие. Я исправил это костылем, запихнув одинаковые шансы друг в друга, но если шансы изменить на неодинаковые, то все перестанет работать. Как это можно исправить?

Код:

```
if (RandomChance <= ThisBox.LegendaryBrawlerChance)
{
    GetBrawler(Rarity.Legendary);
}
else if (RandomChance <= ThisBox.MythicalBrawlerChance && RandomChance > ThisBox.LegendaryBrawlerChance)
{
    GetBrawler(Rarity.Mythical);
}
else if (RandomChance <= ThisBox.EpicBrawlerChance && RandomChance > ThisBox.MythicalBrawlerChance)
{ // Костыль
    int random = Random.Range(0, 2);

    if (random == 0)
    {
        GetBrawler(Rarity.Epic);
    }
    else
    {
        GetBrawler(Rarity.Chromatic);
    }
}
else if (RandomChance <= ThisBox.SuperRareBrawlerChance && RandomChance > ThisBox.EpicBrawlerChance)
{
    GetBrawler(Rarity.SuperRare);
}
else
{
    GetBrawler(Rarity.Rare);
}
```

Comment: Я ничего не понял. Каковы значения `ThisBox.LegendaryBrawlerChance`, `ThisBox.MythicalBrawlerChance` и так далее? Что происходит для конкретного значения `RandomChance`?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1204003/373567

Comment: это что за фреймворк? Unity?

Comment: @aepot Да, юнити

Comment: @Igor LegendaryBrawlerChance - 0.11
MythicalBrawlerChance - 0.26

Comment: Что происходит для конкретного значения RandomChance?

Comment: @Igor Извините случайно нажал опубликовать комментарий
LegendaryBrawlerChance - 0.11 MythicalBrawlerChance - 0.26
EpicBrawlerChance - 0.56, chromatic brawler chance - 0.56
SuperRareBrawlerChance - 1.26 RareBrawlerChance - 2.76

RandomChance может быть от 0 до 2.76 и потом в if выбираю, под какой критерий подходит

Comment: Для какого значения `RandomChance` код ведет себя не так, как Вы ожидаете? Как ведет? Как должен вести?

Comment: @Igor Код ведет себя нормально, но может быть такое, что какие то шанс одинаковы ( в данном фрагменте одинаковы значения Epic Brawler chance и ChromaticBrawlerChance и если все писать if, то выполнится то, чей if стоит первее, так как оба условия верны, но доходит только до первого

Comment: "какие то шанс одинаковы" - я не понимаю, что это значит. Каков смысл чисел `0.26,`, `0.56` и так далее?

Comment: Это шансы. Может выпасть случайное число от 0 до 2.76 и потом идет проверка, начиная с самого маленького, то есть - если случайное число меньше или равно шансу выпадения легендарного бойца(0.11 и получается что число должно быть 0 - 0.11, чтобы условие сработало), если условие неверно, тогда проверять, если меньше или равно шансу выпадения мифического бойца

Answer (score 2):

Лол, как раз только что писал.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Foo
{
    public Foo () 
    {
        // шансы в пропорциях
        float[] Proportions = new[] { 5f, 15f, 20f }; // в сумме 40
        // 0: 12.5% (5/40)
        // 1: 37.5% (15/40)
        // 2: 50% (20/40)
        int Index = GetRandomIndex(Proportions);
    }

    public int GetRandomIndex (float[] proportions)
    {
        float ProportionsSum = proportions.Sum();
        float RandomValue = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, ProportionsSum);
        for (int i = 0; i < proportions.Length; i++)
            if (RandomValue > proportions[i])
                RandomValue -= proportions[i];
            else
                return i;
        throw new Exception("You are suck! Return it as it was.");
    }
}
```

Comment: `return 0;` конфликтует с нулевым индексом. Хотя если оно никогда не случится, я бы бросил исключение в этом месте на случай если мои кривые руки поломают метод в будущем. Типа `throw new SomethingWentWrongException()` :)

Comment: @aepot, если хороший погроммист много пишет код, обязательно что-то поломает .