# Алгоритм выпадения предметов

Tags: java, c#, c++, алгоритм, unity3d

Допустим есть предмет с шансом выпадения 30%. Какие есть **алгоритмы** или **способы**, чтобы осуществить выпадение этого предмета приблизительно в 30% процентов?
Больше интересует именно **описание этого способа**, а не сам готовый код. Как это осуществляется **в реальных проектах** и **играх** или же где можно об этом почитать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: В этом ответе практически полностью высвечивается вопрос даже с самим кодом https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1204156/186752 В ответе от аепот-а - второе решение (более быстрое в работе)

Comment: Чем не нравится Math.Random? Или есть ещё обстоятельства, о которых вы умалчиваете?

Comment: Алгоритм или способ шанса выпадения - пропорцию проходят в средних классах школы. / _Реальные проекты_ - зависит от серьёзности проекта. Это связано с настоящими деньгами? С оборонкой? С гос. тайной? В таких случаях используйте криптографически сильный генератор наподобие [RandomNumberGenerator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator?view=net-5.0)

Answer (score 1):

Известно, что существующие генераторы (псевдо)случайных чисел типа [`Math.random()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random--) возвращают как правило значения в диапазоне `[0.0; 1.0)`.
Соответственно для "генерации" шанса в 30% нужно выбрать в пределах этого диапазона отрезок шириной 0.3:

```java
double r = Math.random();

if (r < 0.3) // [0.0, 0.3)
if (0.2 <= r && r < 0.5) // [0.2, 0.5)
if (r >= 0.7) // [0.7; 1.0)
```

Comment: Это самый простой способ, но он не дает гарантии, что из 100 выборок 30 будут  "верными". В реальных проектах, когда необходимо строго придерживаться шанса - используется сгенерированный список (идентификаторов к примеру) - 30 предметов X (шанс 30%), 10 предметов Y (шанс 10%), 60 предметов Z (60%). И при необходимости берем случайный элемент созданного списка. Игроку "вручаем" данный предмет, а из списка убираем

Comment: Это несколько другая задача на случайный выбор без возвращения (как в лотерее), когда вероятности при каждом следующем выборе изменяются.