# Всегда выпадает одно число

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я изучаю c#. В юнити мне нужно сделать рандом. Я сделал, но по какой-то причине, не известной мне выпадает всё время двойка. Всегда. drop - публичная переменная int равная нулю.

Вот мой код:

```
            //Рандом
            drop = Random.Range(1, 5);
            if (drop == 1)
            {
                nagrada = 10;
                cash += nagrada;
            }
            else if (drop == 2)
            {
                nagrada = 20;
                cash += nagrada;
            }
            else if (drop == 3)
            {
                nagrada = 40;
                cash += nagrada;
            }
            else if (drop == 4)
            {
                nagrada = 50;
                cash += nagrada;
            }
            else
            {
                nagrada = 0;
                cash += nagrada;
            }
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1203937/373567 вдруг пригодится

Comment: можно же сразу писать cash += 10; и т.д. без создания дополнительной переменной

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проверил код, работает.

Скорее всего не весь код показан. Попробуйте с другими числами и в `switch`:

```cs
// (1, 5) означает 1, 2, 3, 4
cash += Random.Range(1, 6) switch
{
    1 => 10,
    2 => 20,
    3 => 40,
    4 => 50,
    _ => 0
};
```

Comment: Да. Действительно не весь код поместил. Проверил у себя, оказывается не туда поместил код выше. С наступающим новым годом! Спасибо!