# Как вычесть шанс из диапазона чисел?

Tags: c#, случайные-числа, range

Есть такой словарь:

```
public Dictionary<int, string> newOreChanse = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
    [15] = "Red",
    [35] = "Green",
    [50] = "Blue"
};
```

Крутим "барабан" из 100 шариков, вытаскивает только один со своим уникальным номером:

```
Random rand = Random.Next(0,99);
```

Нужно представить словарь как один большой диапазон:
`[xxxxyyyyyyzzzzzzzzz]`
(где: `x = Red` - 15% диапазона, `y = Green` - 35% диапазона и `z = Blue` - 50% диапазона).
По сути ключи словаря в роли локального диапазона для своих значений.
То есть если `rand` вернул например 21, а он находится между 15 и 35 то есть нам нужно получить в результате значение "Green".
Как бы Вы решили подобную задачу!?
Надеюсь объяснил понятно.

Comment: в частности советую обратить внимание на мой ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1204156/186752 и на ответ aepot: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1203985/186752

Comment: Согласен очень похоже, мне нужно лишь "повернуть" свой словарь.
Я чего то не могу сообразить как((( наверное просто устал, пару часов сидел над этой делемой.
Понравился самый последний вариант, по моему самый компактный, хорошо попробую.
Пока не закрывайте, может назреют вопросы.

Comment: циклом пройдись по всех Values и по добавляй в массив другим циклом валью количество раз указанное в ключе