# Вопрос на проценты в текстовой игре

Tags: c#

я создаю текстовую игру на c# , встал вопрос. Допустим у меня событие , где персонаж может умереть , как сделать чтобы 50% было что он умрёт , и 50% , что он не умрёт ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1204003/220553

Answer (score 3):

В C# для генерации псевдослучайных чисел существует класс [Random](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.random)

Для имитации случайности, можно написать что-то такое:

```
Random random = new Random();
// Генерация случайного числа от 0 до 1
int randomNumber = random.Next(2);
if (randomNumber == 0)
{
    // Код для смерти персонажа
}
else
{
    // Код для случая, когда персонаж не умирает
}
```