# Хороший ли код?

Tags: c#, unity3d, инспекция-кода

Я написал программу, которая генерирует случайные числа в диапазоне от 0 до 99, и если сгенерированное число попадёт в определенный диапазон, то на экране появится текст, смысл которого зависит от диапазона, в который попадет число. Нормальный ли получился код, или он слишком громоздкий?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class RandomNumberGenerate : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float random_number;
    public Text txt;
    // Update is called once per frame

    void Start()
    {
        random_number = Random.Range(0f, 100f);
        Debug.Log(random_number);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(random_number >= 1 && random_number <= 94f ||  random_number == 0)
    {
        txt.text = "0, 1-94";
    }

    else if (random_number <= 0.01f)
    {
        txt.text = "0.01-0.02";
    }

    else if (random_number >= 95f && random_number <= 98f)
    {
        txt.text = "95-98";
    }

    else if (random_number == 99f)
    {
        txt.text = "99";
    }
    else
        txt.text = "else";
}
```

}

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавляйте код в текстовом виде, а не в графическом...

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119/#12120)

Comment: Дублирование кода есть? Есть. Много if есть? Да. Почему тогда этот код должен быть хорошим?

Comment: вместо if/elseif  можно использовать  https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression  ... тогда станет поинтеренсее....

Comment: Если что, люди заминусили за скриншот, задавать подобные вопросы это нормально.

Comment: Вы хотели [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1203937/373567) написать?

Comment: Чтобы понять корректность написания кода, надо понимать, что за задача стояла перед вами прежде чем вы это написали. В чём смысл этого скрипта, зачем он?

Answer (score 3):

> генерирует случайные числа в диапазоне от 0 до 99, и если
> сгенерированное число попадёт в определенный диапазон, то на экране
> появится текст

- Если ответственность класса нельзя описать односложным предложением, то что-то не так. У тебя банально больше одной ответственности: генерация и визуализация, что нарушает [принцип единственной ответственности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8).
- Для генерации `MonoBehaviour` не нужен. Что делает `Update`? Зачем делать вереницу `if` в каждом кадре с тем-же результатом? `if else if else if else` в наборе однородных операция вообще не должно быть, для этого есть `for`.
- Диапазоны просто выставлены в ручную, прямо в методе, не пойми как, это называется [магические числа](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)). Диапазоны могут пересекаться, полно результатов для которых нет никаких диапазонов, никакого порядка или логики не существует, даже читать больно.
- `public` поля в классе, за что на районе расчехляют вилы и факелы.
- Все названия либо врут, либо не несут смысла.
- Для нейминга полей используют [Camel Case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions#camel-case), это стандарт.
- Кривая табуляция строк, читаемость падает до `кровь из глаз`.
- В коде комментарии из шаблона `MonoBehaviour`, которые к тому-же еще и не на своем месте, грязный мусор как есть.

Какие-то пункты могут показаться придирками и мелочью, но это не так, код должен быть похож на хирургическую палату а не свалку. На любом ревью форматирование и стандарты это первое, что бросается в глаза и если видно, что писал неряха, содержание могут даже не смотреть.

Comment: Это не "мнение". То что это "вкусовщина" одно из заблуждений, все описано. Ноль отсебятины, что такое "Хороший код" не я придумал. По каждому языку есть своя конвенция написания, для С# это [Design Guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/) от самих Microsoft (пункт Camel Case от туда), что касается архитектуры, есть принципы **SOLID**, в остальном мелочи описанные в общепризнанной всеми литературе, о выборе имен, комментариях и многом другом, та-же книга "Чистый код".

Comment: Ну и конечно ЛОГИКА! Не нужен никакой стандарт, конвенция, принцип или о боже "МНЕНИЕ", что бы сказать что делать в `Update` одно и то-же с одними и теми-же вводными и результатом, это говнокод.

Comment: Вы говорили, что для генерации MonoBehaviour и Update не нужны, то есть их удалить?Извиняюсь за такие глупые вопросы, просто я начинающий разработчик и очень многого не знаю.