# Вывод True или Fasle с задаваемым шансом

Tags: c#

Нужно, что бы метод выдавал `True` или `False` с задаваемой вероятностью.

Условно, задал вероятность **0.5** и при **100** попытках на выходе получил ***~ равное количество исходов***.

Или задал вероятность **0.25** и при **100** попытках на выходе получил ***~ 25 и 100***

Либо должен с вероятностью **N** выводить **X** или **X*2**,
где N - задаваемая вероятность, X - int/double переменная

Comment: В чем конкретно заключается проблема?

Comment: Алгоритм/метод должен просто выдавать X или X * 2 с задаваемым шансом

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1204003/220553