Как отследить положение курсора в C# Unity2D
Всем привет, я новичок в программировании и для портфолио решил сделать кликер.
P.S. Ты тыкаешь на камень с определенным шансом тебе выпадает та или иная руда.
Саму систему выпадения руд я сделал, но хочу чтобы при нажатии создавался эффект типа:
Partical System, как-бы понятно, что эффект нужно создавать на координатах позиции мышки, но как? Я немного не понимаю как это сделать :), всем заранее спасибо за помощь. Код: (Пожалуйста не пишите если код ужасный, я сам это подозреваю, можете дать подсказки и тд, буду очень благодарен)
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class Clicker : MonoBehaviour
{
    System.Random r = new System.Random();
    [Header("Effects")]
    public ParticleSystem ClickerEffect;
    [Header("RudaCods")]
    public int RudaCode;
    [Header("Ruds")]
    
    public Text MetallScore;
    public Text SerebroScore;
    public Text MedScore;
    public Text GoldScore;
    public Text AlmazScore;
    public Text BronzeScore;
    public Text KamenScore;
    public Text SuperRudaScore;

    [Header("RudsScore")]
    public int MetallClciks = 0;
    public int AlmazClciks = 0;
    public int KamenClciks = 0;
    public int GoldClciks = 0;
    public int MedClciks = 0;
    public int SerebroClciks = 0;
    public int SuperRudaClciks = 0;
    public int BronzeClciks = 0;
    void Update()
    {
       RudaCode = r.Next(0, 1000);
    }
    public void Click()
    {

        if(RudaCode > 650 && RudaCode < 749)
        {
            MetallClciks++;
            MetallScore.text = MetallClciks.ToString();
        }
        if(RudaCode > 850 && RudaCode < 899)
        {
            SerebroClciks++;
            SerebroScore.text = SerebroClciks.ToString();
        }
        if(RudaCode > 750 && RudaCode < 849)
        {
            MedClciks++;
            MedScore.text = MedClciks.ToString();
        }
        if(RudaCode > 950 && RudaCode < 975)
        {
            GoldClciks++;
            GoldScore.text = GoldClciks.ToString();
        }
        if(RudaCode > 975 && RudaCode < 999)
        {
            AlmazClciks++;
            AlmazScore.text = AlmazClciks.ToString();
        }
        if(RudaCode > 0 && RudaCode < 499)
        {
            KamenClciks++;
            KamenScore.text = KamenClciks.ToString();
        }
        if(RudaCode == 1000)
        {
            SuperRudaClciks++;
            SuperRudaScore.text = SuperRudaClciks.ToString();
        }
        if(RudaCode > 500 && RudaCode < 649)
        {
            BronzeClciks++;
            BronzeScore.text = BronzeClciks.ToString();
        }
    }



https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-mousePosition.html 2) https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html 3) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1203937/373567


Спасибо огромное, очень помог.
